# RXTX read(byte [] buf, int off, int len) returns less than len bytes

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I'm using the RXTX library and after succesfully opening a serial port ("COM1") and setting the receive timeout:

```
commport.enableReceiveTimeout(2000) 
in = commport.getInputStream();
```

When I call the following:

```
byte[] buf = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int rd = in.read(buf, 0, 4);
```

The read() returns even if not all the 4 bytes are received.

> Is it the correct behaviour of the read(buf, off, len) function ? (*there isn't much about it on the official javacomm API documentation*)

In my "expectations", the read(buf,off,buf) should wait until `len` characters are read or raise an Exception on a timeout condition.

> Is there a clean way to implement the "read `len` bytes or raise an exception on timeout"? I could read 1-byte at a time (int read()) and "manually" check the timeout condition using getTickCount(); but it doesn't seem a great solution ...

Comment: Do you use this implementation: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page ?

Comment: Yes, both versions 2.1.7 and 2.2pre2 have the same beahviour